# How to "disable" HD screens for Windows Phone app Store?

Tags: windows-phone-7, screen-resolution

When I started working on our company's Windows Phone app project there was no full HD resolution for WP. But now there is and I'm supposed to disable the app for full HD devices in the WP Store. How do I exactly do that?

The main reason for this is that the app has a thick black ribbon on top of the screen when used with a full HD device.

I have noticed that when you update or upload .xap file, the Store recognizes the requirements of the app. The Store says the app works on all screens. How do I set the requirements so that the app is disabled HD resolution screens?

The app is made to support WP versions 7.1 through 8. I eyed the Internet for help but it seems that because the app is WP 7 compatible I can't describe the resolutions in the WMAppManifest where the Store would easily to find it. Or can I?

It would be so great if I could do this some easy way instead of going through the whole app to make it work "better" on HD screens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how you can prevent users with certain display resolutions from installing your app. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610479/restrict-the-windows-phone-app-for-specific-devices), it was about installation prevention of apps for specific device types. What you can do is to do the check in code.

You could check the device's display resolution when starting the application. If the size exceeds your limit, you could inform the user about that and exit the application.

[How can I get a screen resolution of Device (Windows Phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852416/how-can-i-get-a-screen-resolution-of-device-windows-phone)

However, I don't know how this would affect the app certification.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7.1 only supports 800 x 480 resolution and Windows Phone 8 supports multiple resolution.

The scaling used for Windows Phone 7x apps on Windows Phone 8 means that one 720p and 1080p devices, you will get a black band. There is nothing you can do.

You could recompile the app as Windows Phone 8 app and have both WP7x and WP8 xaps available and this will ensure that the space is consumed correctly and the black band isn't shown.